# How do I create a raw MongoDB Query using Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to query embedded documents using dot notation -- here are some examples:

[http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+(Reaching+into+Objects)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29)

Since I'm hung up on the DQL/QueryBuilder API I'd like to just pass raw queries through Doctrine. I can't seem to figure this out within the constructs of Symfony2. The only code I can be sure of is:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$dm->getSchemaManager()->ensureIndexes();
$repo = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:MyDocument');
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder();

// insert magic here

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute();
```

Here's how dot notation works:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$dm->getSchemaManager()->ensureIndexes();
$repo = $dm->getRepository('MyBundle:MyDocument');
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->field('embedded_document_field.field1')->equals(1)
    ->field('embedded_document_field.field2')->equals('foo')
;

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is ancient, but in case someone comes across it, it's fairly straightforward to do this with the Query Builder:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('embedded.embedded2.username')->equals($username));
    $qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('embedded.embedded3.username')->equals($username));
    $qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('embedded.embedded4.username')->equals($username));
    $qb->field('status')->lt(10);
    $involved = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    return $involved;
```

I acknowledge this doesn't actually answer the question relating to passing through raw (which is my own question) but it does solve your problem.